# Sphinx: Permission denied/Broken pipe on deltas merge

Tags: windows, sphinx

When i launch this batch command for create and merge deltas:

```
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf idx_product_delta --rotate
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf --merge idx_product_main idx_product_delta --rotate
```

In searchd.log found this error and deltas are not merged into main

```
[Fri Sep 25 15:34:42.549 2015] [ 2312] WARNING: rotating index 'idx_product_main': cur to old rename failed: rename D:\Sphinx\project\data\product.spa to D:\Sphinx\project\data\product.old.spa failed: Broken pipe
```

Console output is:

```
using config file 'D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf'...
merging index 'idx_product_delta' into index 'idx_product_main'...
read 7.2 of 7.2 MB, 100.0% done
merged 11.5 Kwords
merged in 0.127 sec
ERROR: index 'idx_product_main': failed to delete 'D:\Sphinx\project\data\product.new.spa': Permission deniedtotal 671 reads, 0.006 sec, 15.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg total 36 writes, 0.004 sec, 277.8 kb/call avg, 0.1 msec/call avg
```

My product.conf is:

```
source src_product_main
{
    type = mysql

    sql_host = localhost
    sql_user = root
    sql_pass =
    sql_db = database
    sql_port = 3306 # optional, default is 3306

    sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sphinx_index_meta(index_name, last_update) \
                    VALUES('idx_prodotti_main', current_timestamp())


    sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) \
                      FROM product \
                      WHERE deleted = 0 AND visible= 1

    sql_range_step = 1000

    sql_query = SELECT id, text, last_update \
                FROM product \
                WHERE id>=$start AND id<=$end AND deleted = 0 AND visible = 1

    sql_attr_timestamp = last_update
}


index idx_product_main
{
    source = src_product_main
    path = D:\Sphinx\project\data\product
    ondisk_attrs = 1
    stopwords = D:\Sphinx\project\stopwords.txt

    min_word_len = 2
    min_prefix_len = 0
    min_infix_len = 3
    ngram_len = 1
}


source src_product_delta : src_product_main
{
    sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) \
                      FROM product \
                      WHERE deleted = 0 AND visible= 1

    sql_range_step = 1000

    sql_query = SELECT id, text, last_update \
                FROM product \
                WHERE id>=$start AND id<=$end AND deleted = 0 AND visible = 1
}


index idx_product_delta : idx_product_main
{
    source = src_product_delta
    path = D:\Sphinx\project\delta\product
    ondisk_attrs = 1
    stopwords = D:\Sphinx\project\stopwords.txt

    min_word_len = 2
    min_prefix_len = 0
    min_infix_len = 3
    ngram_len = 1
}


indexer
{
    mem_limit = 128M
    max_iosize = 1M
}


searchd
{
    listen = 9312
    listen = 9306:mysql41
    log = D:\Sphinx\project\log\searchd.log
    query_log = D:\Sphinx\project\log\query.log
    read_timeout = 5
    client_timeout = 300
    max_children = 30
    pid_file = D:\Sphinx\project\log\searchd.pid
    seamless_rotate = 1
    preopen_indexes = 0
    unlink_old = 1
    workers = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path = D:\Sphinx\project\data
}
```

I have also tried on Windows 7 and Windows 8, with both stable 2.2.10 and beta
2.3.1-id64-beta (r4926) with same error.

- indexer running with a cron (windows scheduler) as SYSTEM user
- searchd service running as SYSTEM user
- D:\Sphinx\project\data\ folder permission has full control for SYSTEM

How can I solve this issue

**UPDATE** for [Eugene Soldatov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32849889/2936170)

I have also tried (first command less --rotate)

```
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf idx_product_delta
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf --merge idx_product_main idx_product_delta --rotate
```

but in console output found this error

```
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file 'D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf'...
indexing index 'idx_prodotti_delta'...
FATAL: failed to lock D:\Sphinx\project\delta\prodotti.spl: No error, will not index. Try --rotate option.
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file 'D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf'...
merging index 'idx_prodotti_delta' into index 'idx_prodotti_main'...
read 7.2 of 7.2 MB, 100.0% done
merged 11.5 Kwords
merged in 0.214 sec
ERROR: index 'idx_prodotti_main': failed to delete 'D:\Sphinx\project\data\prodotti.new.spa': Permission deniedtotal 20136 reads, 0.071 sec, 30.9 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 36 writes, 0.012 sec, 283.3 kb/call avg, 0.3 msec/call avg
```

In searchd.log found this error

```
[Wed Sep 30 09:09:29.371 2015] [ 4244] rotating index 'idx_prodotti_main': started
[Wed Sep 30 09:09:29.381 2015] [ 4244] WARNING: rotating index 'idx_prodotti_main': cur to old rename failed: rename D:\Sphinx\project\data\prodotti.spa to D:\Sphinx\project\data\prodotti.old.spa failed: Broken pipe
[Wed Sep 30 09:09:29.381 2015] [ 4244] rotating index: all indexes done
```

**UPDATE 2**

Also try to insert sleep between two commands

```
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf idx_product_delta --rotate
timeout /t 60
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf --merge idx_product_main idx_product_delta --rotate
```

Console output:

```
ERROR: index 'idx_prodotti_main': failed to delete 'D:\Sphinx\project\data\prodotti.new.spa': Permission deniedtotal 20137 reads, 0.072 sec, 30.9 kb/c
```

**UPDATE 3: Issue solved**

Issue solved by sphinx guys here

http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=2335

Answer (score 2):

The reason of such behavior is that --rotate command is asynchronous, so when you run second command:

```
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf --merge idx_product_main idx_product_delta --rotate
```

first may continue to work with index idx_product_delta:

```
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf idx_product_delta --rotate
```

, so it's locked.

If it's possible, remove --rotate option on first command.

UPDATE:

Seems that you need --rotate option in first command. So you could measure average time that need to make it done and insert sleep between two commands. For example, for 30 seconds:

```
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf idx_product_delta --rotate
timeout /t 30
D:\Sphinx\bin\indexer.exe --config D:\Sphinx\project\product.conf --merge idx_product_main idx_product_delta --rotate
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I have tried your tip but this raise me a similar exception. I have updated my question.

Comment: Index are ok, but fails on merge... :(    (answer updated)

Comment: Did you try to run your batch-script by hands (from admin account)?